# Order the options of a select list

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php for loop that generates a select list, but I can't figure out how to order the options of the list the way I want.

This is the php:

```
static function tp_widget_do($args) {
  echo '<span class="' . NO_TRANSLATE_CLASS . '">';

  echo '<select name="lang" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">'; 

  foreach ($args as $langrecord) {
    $is_selected = $langrecord['active'] ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "";
    echo "<option value=\"{$langrecord['url']}\"{$is_selected}>{$langrecord['langorig']}</option>";
  }
  echo "</select><br/>";

  echo "</span>";
}
```

I was thinking of using either 'arsort' or maybe even some javascript to sort the list of options. If I could sort them alphabetically and then by reverse order, that'd be ideal.

Comment: You have to use `usort()` because it's a 2-dimensional array, and there's no built-in sort function that will sort a multidimensional array based on a particular column. You could split them into separate arrays and use `array_multisort()`; see Example #3 in http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: Okay. How would I split them into seperate arrays?

Comment: Like I said, see the example in the documentation.

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.4+, you can use `array_column()` instead of the loop.